# Parse User log out does not work

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, android-facebook

I am using Parse 1.9.0 for Android and I need to log out user on button click, so I call:

```
ParseUser.logOut();
```

After that I need to open login screen and click on Facebook login button, and to check if user have saved custom custom field.

But, it seems that `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` after log out is not null.

How I can remove current user from cache?

Comment: Do you have automatic users enabled?

Comment: I had, but I have turned it off  before 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ParseUser.logOut();
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); // this will now be null
```

Comment: @Tokimu, this will not be null actually, that's what this question about.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you want to do! But you can check at the `onCreate` method if the Current User is an Anonymous user and thus prevent it to auto-load Anonymous userData from the cache:

```
if (ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())) {
    //This is a Logged out Anonymous user
} else {
    //Getting Current User who is not logged off
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
        //Do your staff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `logout()` method is called from the current user object itself and to obtain it you call `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` and then logout like below:

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().logOut();
```

now the current user is null.
if `ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();` isn't called anywhere the current user will only be logged in using :

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password);
ParseUser parseUser = /*your user data here*/;
parseUser.signUpInBackground();
```